# Richfaces+SEAM: good doc describing s:decorate tag functionality?

Tags: xhtml, richfaces, seam

EDIT: Would it be more elegant to tweak the GUI using CSS, or some other way?

Is there any good documentation (the official one only shows a basic example) for this tag?

I want to use it like this:

```
<s:decorate template="template.xhtml">
....richfaces UI...
</s:decorate>
```

in order to format a list of question-answer pairs without using rich tables or nested panels.

I get the gist of what it does, but I don't understand exactly how I can edit my own template.xhtml files and make the UI look as I want by using it.

Comment: Caved in and gave up on the decorate tag. Used instead a h:panelGrid with two columns (one for questions, the other for the respective answers), styled with CSS. If there's a more elegant way, I'd like to hear any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `s:decorate` is basically the same as `ui:decorate` with some extra functionality like `rendered`

The ui:decorate can be explained as:

> The UI Decorate tag is a templating
>   tag that decorates content included
>   from another Facelet. Any content
>   outside of the UI Decorate tag will be
>   displayed by the Facelets view
>   handler. Any content within the
>   decorate tag will be passed to the
>   associated template as parameters or
>   simply ignored. You can use nested
>   ui:define tags to pass named content
>   to the associated template. See
>   ui:insert for more information.

For more info you can read [here](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/facelets/10-TagReference/facelets-ui-decorate.html) and [here](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.1.CR1/reference/en-US/html/controls.html#controls.tags)

To answer your update question. You should also use CSS to style the content of your template